# Pip and pip3 not working after python3.7.10 installation

Tags: linux, terminal, pip

I have this error while installing pip. Previously, I had python 3.5.2 which I upgraded to python 3.7.10. Then I changed the default python3 version by using this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2
```

after that, whenever I use pip or pip3, it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Now while attempting to install pip, this error shows up..

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2) but 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
 installed
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling python completely and reinstalling it back even check the paths once

Comment: tried doing that..can't run few commands due this broken packages

Answer (score 0):

```
python3.9 -m pip install pip
```

This could help